# Need help masking a the skin on the face from the skin on hand with OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Lets say I have an image as such :[Sign Language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ddo1v.png)

After isolating skin in the image, it looks like : [The skin on the hand and face are isolated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKDjJ.jpg)

How would I mask the skin on the face such that I only get the hands from the images?

Edit:

How I isolated the skin from the image:

```
import cv2
import sys
import numpy

im = cv2.imread("test.png")

im_ycrcb = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)
skin_ycrcb_mint = numpy.array((0, 133, 77))
skin_ycrcb_maxt = numpy.array((255, 173, 127))
skin_ycrcb = cv2.inRange(im_ycrcb, skin_ycrcb_mint, skin_ycrcb_maxt)
cv2.imwrite("testing.jpg", skin_ycrcb)
```

Comment: Please share the approach you've tried so far, show some research.

Comment: Edited to show work.

Comment: The face should be bigger, rounder and should move less. Have you separated the 3 groups (left hand, right hand, face) by some means (clustering, contours)?  If so, are there any properties of those groups that are consistently different? Have you done research into hand detection? https://ac.els-cdn.com/S1877050915020682/1-s2.0-S1877050915020682-main.pdf?_tid=07502588-b0df-482d-9d3f-c474e6acbc00&acdnat=1528219246_aa9dc2c4ec1329991f2ab93c29b581a5

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at the link you posted.